# Computing $K_1(l^\infty(\mathbb{N}))$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Let $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ be the $C^*$-algebra of bounded sequences $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{C}$.

I would like to compute the $K_1(l^\infty(\mathbb{N}))$, which I suspect is the zero group. However, I'm not sure how to argue this rigorously.

**Question:** How would one show that $K_1(l^\infty(\mathbb{N}))=0$? (A reference would be great also.)

*Thoughts:* My first thought was that because $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})=\prod_{\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{C}$, one could use the fact that operator $K$-theory respects direct products. However, for infinite products I think this is only true if each factor in the product has some additional stability property.

Comment: I think this was discussed on this site before, but I don't find the question right now. The $K_1$-group of any von Neumann algebra is trivial: Any unitary is path connected to the identity by Borel functional calculus. Since $M_n\otimes M$ is again a von Neumann algebra, this implies that $U_n(M)/U_n(M)_0$ is trivial for all $n$, hence so is $K_1(M)$.

Comment: I think this is the post I meant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155943/what-is-k-1bh-operator-k-theory